# GtkSpinner with long-lasting function with C

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm making a GTK+3 application in C and I want a spinner to show when the program is processing the data. Here's what I generally have:

```
main()
{
    //Some statements
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btnGenerate), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Generate), &mainform);
}
void Generate(GtkWidget *btnGenerate, form_widgets *p_main_form)
{
    gtk_spinner_start(GTK_SPINNER(p_main_form->spnProcessing));
    Begin_Lengthy_Processing(Parameters, Galore, ...);
    //gtk_spinner_stop(GTK_SPINNER(p_main_form->spnProcessing));
}
```

I have the stop function commented out so I can see the spinner spin even after the function has finished, but the spinner *starts* after the function is finished, and I suspect it turns on in the main loop.

I also found out that the entire interface freezes during the execution of the long going function.

Is there a way to get it to start and display inside the callback function? I found the same question, but it uses Python and threads. This is C, not Python, so I would assume things are different.

Comment: Yes, you will need to run the lengthy process on another thread and return control to `gtk_main()` to keep the GUI respondent and animating. You can use `gdk_threads_add_idle()` or `g_idle_add()` to communicate to the GUI thread; communicating in the opposite direction is up to you.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your lengthy computation in a separate thread, or break it up into chunks and run each of them separately as idle callbacks in the main thread.

If your lengthy computation takes a single set of inputs and doesn’t need any more inputs until it’s finished, then you should construct it as a [`GTask`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html) and use [`g_task_run_in_thread()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html#g-task-run-in-thread) to start the task. Its result will be delivered back to the main thread via the `GTask`’s `GAsyncReadyCallback`. There’s an example [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GTask.html#id-1.4.5.4.9.5).

If it takes more input as it progresses, you probably want to use a [`GAsyncQueue`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html) to feed it more inputs, and a [`GThreadPool`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Thread-Pools.html) to provide the threads (amortising the cost of creating threads over multiple calls to the lengthy function, and protecting against denial of service).

The GNOME developer docs give an [overview of how to do threading](https://developer.gnome.org/programming-guidelines/stable/threading.html.en).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
int main()
{
    // Statements...
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btnGenerate), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Process), &mainform);
    // More statements...
}
void Process(GtkWidget *btnGenerate, form_widgets *p_main_form)
{
    GError *processing_error;
    GThread *start_processing;
    gtk_spinner_start(GTK_SPINNER(p_main_form->spnProcessing));
    active = true;
    if((start_processing = g_thread_try_new(NULL, (GThreadFunc)Generate, p_main_form, &processing_error)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", processing_error->message);
        printf("Error, cannot create thread!?!?\n\n");
        exit(processing_error->code);
    }
}
void Generate(form_widgets *p_main_form)
{
    // Long process
    active = false;
}
```

My program, once cleaned up and finished, as there are many other bugs in the program, will be put on GitHub.

Thank you all for your help. This answer comes from looking at all of your answers and comments as well as reading some more documentation, but mostly your comments and answers.

Answer (score -3):

I did something similar in my gtk3 program. It's not that difficult. Here's how I would go about it.

```
/**
 g_idle_add_full() expects a pointer to a function with the signature below:
(*GSourceFunc) (gpointer user_data).

So your function signature must adhere to that in order to be called.
But you might want to pass variables to the function.
If you don't want to have the variables in the global scope
then you can do this:

typedef struct myDataType {
    char* name;
    int age;
} myDataType;

myDataType person = {"Max", 25};

then when calling g_idle_add_full() you do it this way:
    g_idle_add_full(G_PRIORITY_HIGH_IDLE, myFunction, person, NULL);
*/

int main()
{
    // Assumming there exist a pointer called data
    g_idle_add_full(G_PRIORITY_HIGH_IDLE, lengthyProcessCallBack, data, NULL);

    // GTK & GDK event loop continues and window should be responsive while function runs in background
}

gboolean lengthyProcessCallBack(gpointer data)
{
    myDataType person = (myDataType) *data;

    // Doing lenghthy stuff
    while(;;) { 
        sleep(3600); // hypothetical long process :D
    }

    return FALSE; // removed from event sources and won't be called again.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing how to use `g_idle_add_full()`, but where do I put the `gtk_spinner_start()`? I want the spinner to spin to show that the program is not dead, but processing.

Comment: This is not correct. The idle function has to return to the main loop in order for the GUI to work. You must either break the process apart or use a thread; look up the GLib documentation for a thread API that comes with GTK+'s dependencies.

Comment: I was looking at the threads, and this is what I have: `g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(btnGenerate), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Process), &mainform);` and in the Process function: `GThread *start_spinner = g_thread_new(NULL, (GThreadFunc)Toggle_Spinner, NULL);
 GThread *start_processing = g_thread_new(NULL, (GThreadFunc)Generate, p_main_form);` but I get a Segmentation Fault. I can't find a good tutorial on using GThreads. Note: Generate is the lengthy process.

Comment: Can you show us your code if possible?, Also I recommend you give my answer a shot.

Comment: @techdude1996 you should call `gtk_spinner_start()` inside of the callback in the above answer. The call would be inside of `lengthyProcessCallBack()`, but then, of course, you'd need the pointer to the `GtkSpinner` which you could get by `GtkSpinner *spinner = (GtkSpinner*) *data;`

Comment: Then where/how do I run the lengthy process if the callback is being used for the spinner?

Comment: @techdude1996 I think you can then use `g_thread_new` inside of the callback as the long process will not need to do anything with the gtk objects. Share  your code please so I may offer a better solution.